# Undefined ustring in gtkmm 3.0

Tags: c++, include, gtkmm

I'm in Code::Blocks, and for whatever reason, I cannot get started with gtkmm-3.0. Under Project -> Build options... -> Compiler settings --> Other options, I included the following...

```
`pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
`pkg-config glibmm-2.4 --cflags --libs`
```

Obviously that should set everything up for using gtkmm-3.0 (which is indeed installed fully and properly), but I am getting errors from inside gtkmm-3.0.

> /usr/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:37: undefined reference to 
>   `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
>   /usr/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:37: undefined reference to`
>   Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
>   /usr/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:38: undefined reference to 
>   `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
>   /usr/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:38: undefined reference to`
>   Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
>   /usr/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:39: undefined reference to 
>   `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
>   /usr/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:39: undefined reference to`
>   Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
>   /usr/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:40: undefined reference to 
>   `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
>   /usr/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:40: undefined reference to`
>   Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
>   /usr/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:41: undefined reference to 
>   `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
>   /usr/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:41: undefined reference to`
>   Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
>   /usr/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:42: undefined reference to 
>   `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
>   /usr/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:42: undefined reference to`
>   Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
>   /usr/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:43: undefined reference to 
>   `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
>   /usr/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/papersize.h:43: undefined reference to`
>   Glib::ustring::~ustring()'

I do NOT want to switch to another IDE. I like CodeBlocks. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow, I figured this out. Go to Project --> Build options --> Linker settings. Under "Other linker options", put the following...

```
`pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --libs`
`pkg-config glibmm-2.4 --libs`
```

(Note, this is identical to the code in Compiler settings, except without `--cflags`. For me, that resolved the issue immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `--cflags` did not help me – I just got a different error.

After a lot of research, I found that I was getting this error because gtkmm is statically linked and the libraries need to be at the end. If I move the back-ticked text to the end of the compiler/linker lines it works.

This is the makefile text I ended up with to get it working:

```
g++ --std=c++17 -p ${SOURCE} -o ${TARGET} -W -Wall -pedantic `/usr/bin/pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```